# Does x:uid work at design time or not?

Tags: uwp

Please tell us, is it possible to load strings and other properties of a control at design time using x:uid in UWP?

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 2):

Not possible, the resource file values are not applied at design time.

Comment: can you tell us, what are differences b/w Resourcedictionary(.xaml) and Resource(.resw) files.

Comment: sorry, bad terminology, I meant resource file (.resw)

Answer (score 0):

What you *can* do to provide design-time values:

```
Content="{x:Bind MyProperty, FallbackValue='Hello, world!'}"
```

...which works both for `x:Bind` compile-time bindings and dynamic `Binding`s.